# Does Google Calendar API allow appointment Scheduling in a multi-vendor React Web App?

Tags: reactjs, api, calendar, google-calendar-api, appointment

I have my Web Application which has **REACT JS client side** and **PHP APIs for server** end.

This system has two main features:
1) Customers can buy products from multiple Vendors
2) Customers can **schedule Vehicle Maintenance Services** from multiple Vendors

For the Part 2, I want **help**. There are multiple vendors and each Vendor has their own **Workers/Mechanics** with various **working Hours**.

**I want a calendar where Vendor can Add the various working hours for each Worker** like

Worker ABC ---- Mon, Tue from 08:00 to 12:00

Worker XYZ ---- Fri, Sat, Sun 04:00 to 06:00 and 09:00 to 10:00

And Customer can select any maintenance **Service** and then he can **schedule time** for that service according to the **Availability** of Workers of that Vendor whose Service he's requesting. Suppose he selects a service provided by the above Vendor then customer should be able to select only above mentioned **time slots** for scheduling.

Now I want **recommendation** for either Using **Google Calendar API** for this or WHAT to use? Im so confused because this is **multi vendor App** and each vendor has their own Login account. So Im not sure if Google Calendar works with only a single calendar or I can have different calendar for each vendor?